Error when I am using package persistent_bottom_nav_bar
when I use persistent_bottom_nav_bar package in my Flutter app,
this error is appearing
Error: The getter 'backgroundColor' isn't defined for the class 'ThemeData'.
 - 'ThemeData' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/theme_data.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/theme_data.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'backgroundColor'.
    final color = decoration.color ?? Theme.of(context).backgroundColor;
                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^`

when trying to run. How can I fix it?

this package is old and is using some old theme properties which has been removed in newer version of flutter. instead of this use persistent_bottom_nav_bar_v2

as the persistent_bottom_nav_bar_v2 says that it is the continuation of the  persistent_bottom_nav_bar

Try upgrading the version to the latest
persistent_bottom_nav_bar: ^6.0.0

This version worked for me
